# Getting error with mongod (2.8) "error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, mongodb, openssl, opensuse

When I run mongod (from version 2.8), I get the error:

```
mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried fixing this by running:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10
sudo ln -s /lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libssl.so.10
```

And also:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /lib/libcrypto.so.10
sudo ln -s /lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 /lib/libssl.so.10
```

But it doesn't work, I get the same error.

If I instead do:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 /lib64/libssl.so.10
```

I get the error:

```
mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Computer OS: openSUSE LEAP 42.1 KDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by symlinking the 64 bit versions instead of 32 bit:

```
sudo ln -s /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /lib64/libcrypto.so.10
sudo ln -s /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0 /lib64/libssl.so.10
```